# GCP Cloud Batch fails with the GPU instance template

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run a GCP Cloud Batch job (catboost training) with K80 GPU. CAtboost fails with the default driver version Cloud Batch installs to the instance, forcing me to create my own instance template. I used CentOS 7 and NVIDIA 470 drivers.

The job runs for ~30 min. and then fails. The error logs say:

```
status: {
  code: 5
  message: "The resource 'cloudbatch/vmstate' of type 'Guest Attribute' was not found."
}
```

How can I fix that?

Alternatively, is there a way to specify the NVIDIA driver version for the cloud batch GPU jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch has added a flag "driverVersion" to control the NVIDIA driver version. See https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs#accelerator